# How to get the radio value in the if statement?

Tags: android, flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  home: BmiMain(),
);
}
}

class BmiMain extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_BmiMainState createState() => _BmiMainState();
}

enum Gender {MAN, WOMEN}
enum Activity{LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH}

class _BmiMainState extends State<BmiMain> {
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
final _heightController = TextEditingController();
final _weightController = TextEditingController();
final _ageController = TextEditingController();

Gender _gender = Gender.MAN;
Activity _activity = Activity.LOW;

@override
void dispose() {
_heightController.dispose();
_weightController.dispose();
_ageController.dispose();
super.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Diary')),
  body: Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    child: Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: 'Height',
            ),
            controller: _heightController,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.trim().isEmpty) {
                return 'Height : ';
              }
              return null;
            },
            // )
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 16.0,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: 'Weight',
            ),
            controller: _weightController,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.trim().isEmpty) {
                return 'Weight : ';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 16.0,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: 'Age',
            ),
            controller: _ageController,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.trim().isEmpty) {
                return 'Age : ';
              }
              return null;
            },
            // )
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 16.0,
          ),
          RadioListTile(
            title: Text('MEN'),
            value: Gender.MAN,
            groupValue: _gender,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _gender = value;
              });
            },
          ),
          RadioListTile(
            title: Text('WOMEN'),
            value: Gender.WOMEN,
            groupValue: _gender,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _gender = value;
              });
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 16.0,
          ),
          RadioListTile(
            title: Text('No exercise'),
            value: Activity.LOW,
            groupValue: _activity,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _activity = value;
              });
            },
          ),
          RadioListTile(
            title: Text('Exercise three to five times a week'),
            value: Activity.MEDIUM,
            groupValue: _activity,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _activity = value;
              });
            },
          ),
          RadioListTile(
            title: Text('Exercise six to seven times a week'),
            value: Activity.HIGH,
            groupValue: _activity,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _activity = value;
              });
            },
          ),
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => BmiResult(
                            double.parse(_heightController.text.trim()),
                            double.parse(_weightController.text.trim()),
                            double.parse(_ageController.text.trim()))),
                  );
                }
              },
              child: Text('결과'),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}

class BmiResult extends StatelessWidget {

final double height;
final double weight;
final double age;

BmiResult(this.height, this.weight, this.age);

get basal => null;

get _gender => null;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final bmi = weight / ((height / 100) * (height / 100));
// ignore: unrelated_type_equality_checks
if(_gender == Gender.MAN){
  final basal = 66.47+(13.75*weight)+(5*height)-(6.76*age);
}else if(_gender == Gender.WOMEN){
  final basal = 65.51+(9.56*weight)+(1.85*height)-(4.68*age);
}
print('bmi : $bmi');
print('basal : $basal');

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Result')),
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          _calcBmi(bmi),
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 36),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 16,
        ),
        _buildIcon(bmi),
        Text(
          basal,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}

String _calcBmi(double bmi) {
var result = 'underweight';
if (bmi >= 35) {
  result = 'high obesity';
} else if (bmi >= 30) {
  result = 'two-stage obesity';
} else if (bmi >= 25) {
  result = 'first-stage obesity';
} else if (bmi >= 23) {
  result = 'overweight';
}else if(bmi>=18.5){
  result='normal';
}
return result;
}

Widget _buildIcon(double bmi) {
if (bmi >= 23) {
  return Icon(
    Icons.sentiment_very_dissatisfied,
    color: Colors.red,
    size: 100,
  );
} else if (bmi >= 18.5) {
  return Icon(
    Icons.sentiment_satisfied,
    color: Colors.green,
    size: 100,
  );
} else {
  return Icon(
    Icons.sentiment_dissatisfied,
    color: Colors.orange,
    size: 100,
  );
}
}
}
```

I'm developing an app that calculates obesity, basic metabolic rate, and active metabolic rate as a practice. I've created a radio widget that allows you to choose between men and women, but I'm going to use it to calculate basic metabolic rates, and I don't know how to get the radio values from the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method. I am using `enum` as a variable and assigning a value to it

From my point of view, I think this method is easy and simple. I will give you an example that I hope will benefit you:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

enum RadioGender { male, female }

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  RadioGender radioGender;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(radioGender == RadioGender.male
                  ? Icons.radio_button_checked
                  : Icons.radio_button_off),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  radioGender = RadioGender.male;
                  _checkTypeSelect();
                });
              },
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            Text(
              'Male',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 32.0,
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(radioGender == RadioGender.female
                  ? Icons.radio_button_checked
                  : Icons.radio_button_off),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  radioGender = RadioGender.female;
                  _checkTypeSelect();
                });
              },
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            Text(
              'Female',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _checkTypeSelect() {
    if (radioGender == RadioGender.male) {
      print('You Select Male Radio');
    } else if (radioGender == RadioGender.female) {
      print('You Select Female Radio');
    }
  }
}
```